# Is weight class related to injury risk in combat sports like MMA or boxing?

Tags: boxing, mixed-martial-arts, injury, power, weight

I have a hypothesis that damage resistance (ability to handle destructive impact without damage) is not related to the ability to deliver destructive damage (as a function of body mass) in ratio 1:1 (i.e. your capability to deliver damage is not equal to your ability with withstand damage).

In other words, I guess that if you gain 10% of body weight, that increment of your power in % is not the same as the increment of your damage resistance in % and vice versa.

If this hypothesis is valid, then some weight classes should be safer than others. However, I have a hard time googling any related study or statistics (because of the massive flood of information about weight cutting in a combat sport - this topic is completely occupying the keywords I search for).

So I ask you for help:

1. Are there any studies on this topic?
2. What accessible statistics should be used to run this test?

But, please avoid zero-experience opinions. I have already acquired a bunch of them and they are not really helping.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but not really on topic for fitness. It's late here now, but I'll figure out tomorrow morning whether cross validated or martial arts would be a better location.

Comment: @JohnP I have the same dilemma. I decided for Physical Fitness because the damage resistance and power are fitness qualities trained like other fitness qualities (also in other contact sports - other than combat sports). The Martial arts exchange makes sense maybe also (I was thinking about it). But because this question is not about methodology (or validity) in this stage, I think the Cross validate is not a good option.

Comment: True, although for it to be a better fit here, we would want the training outlined more. I think MA would be a better fit, I'll edit it and migrate.

Comment: See also my answer: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/which-will-result-in-more-brain-damage-being-a-heavy-weight-or-lightweight-boxe/4456#4456

Answer (score 3):

This appears true as measured by brain damage in boxers. The following is the excerpt from the ["A neurologist's reflections on boxing. V. Conclude remarks." by Unterharnscheidt F](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8556585).

> Clinical and morphological publications have shown convincingly, that participation in boxing leads to a severe permanent brain damage. The extent of the brain damage is correlated to the number of bouts fought, which correspondents [sic] in a certain way how many blows against his head a boxer received and to his weight class. The intensity of a boxing blow of a heavyweight is much more severe than those achieved by boxers of lighter weight classes.

[Boxing: Medical Aspects](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=-Vk9C_Cgo20C&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=Unterharnscheidt%20&ots=W0gO6UDbnX&sig=iwoklDYgPf5Pyohfx88Jjvrp4ow#v=onepage&q=Unterharnscheidt&f=false) coauthored by the above author appears to be a good place to start.

Comment: Without reading the paper you're citing (sorry, being lazy), I remember someone pointing out that the sort of trauma varies. Higher weight-classes were more prone to immediate brain injury, but lighter weight-classes tended more toward the post-concussion trauma because they survived more punches without getting sidelined.

Comment: TKD based study - Injuries climb with weight class, except the top 2 weight classes in men drop a bit: https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/html/10.1055/s-0031-1275302